# ComboBox to select first Value when created

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combo box in a ItemControl. xaml is

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.NodeMembershipFunction,
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl},
       AncestorLevel=1}}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="_Name" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Condition, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedValuePath="_Type">
</ComboBox>
```

My combobox works fine with above so I am not posting any code to explain above.

My problem is that when I add a new item to my ItemControl, the combox has nothing selected (which is correct according to the code I have). Is there any way to add a trigger or something in above which selects first item only when nothing is selected eg on adding new itemcontrol?

Comment: You might handle this in the PropertyChangedEvent-Handler of your ItemsSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on comboBox instance so that it always be in sync with current item of collection.

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"..../>
```

---

Moreover, adding item in collection won't make SelectedItem to go away unless you are re-initializing the entire list.

I would suggest to use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for property `NodeMembershipFunction` in case not doing it already and add item directly to the collection instead of repopulating it.